# How to generate an uuid in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, uuid, google-sheets-custom-function

How to generate an uuid in google sheet (for exemple ccb8a660-91c9-a556-58e0-4fa7-229516872004).

Either with a macro? or a formula?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

## Generate UUID

You can generate a UUID using `Utilities.getUuid()`. But it is required to use a custom function because there are no functions for it in Google Sheet's set of functions. In order to generate UUID, please do the following:

1. Open the Google Apps Script editor.
2. Copy and paste the following script and save it.
3. Put `=uuid()` to a cell in a sheet.

#### Script :

```
function uuid() {
  return Utilities.getUuid();
}
```

#### Reference :

- [getUuid()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#getUuid())

## Generate Static UUID

When a custom function is used, the value is changed by the automatic recalculating of Spreadsheet. This example will fix the UUID.

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getFormula().toUpperCase()  == "=UUID(TRUE)") {
    e.range.setValue(Utilities.getUuid());
  }
}

function uuid() {
  return Utilities.getUuid();
}
```

- When you use this script, please do the following flow:

  1. Copy and paste the script to the bound-script of Spreadsheet and save it.
  2. Put `=uuid()` to a cell in a sheet.

     - In this case, `=uuid()` is put as a custom function. So when the Spreadsheet is automatically calculated, the value is changed.
  3. Put `=uuid(true)` to a cell in a sheet.

     - In this case, `=uuid()` is put as a value by `onEdit()`. So even when the Spreadsheet is automatically calculated, the value is NOT changed.

#### Note:

- In this case, `=uuid(true)` can use when the function is manually put, because this uses the OnEdit event trigger.
- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you for the comment. When ``Utilities.getUuid()`` is run, the result value is always difference. But I have no information about whether the created value is changed with the time. I'm sorry for this situation. If I found about the information, I would like to report it. If I misunderstand your comment, please tell me.

Comment: @I'-'I I'm also interested in the change with the time. I would like to try to investigate it. Thank you for providing the interesting theme.

Comment: Is the proposed solution creating a UUID V4? This criteria is crucial in my project

Comment: @tivoni About your question of `Is the proposed solution creating a UUID V4? This criteria is crucial in my project`, the official document of [getUuid()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#getUuid()) says "Get a UUID as a string (equivalent to using [the java.util.UUID.randomUUID() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)).". Is this information useful?

Comment: According to the java.util documentation, it's a uuid V2. Which brings me to the question, is it possible to generate a V4 via the GS Utilities interface?

Comment: @tivoni Thank you for replying. About your new question of `According to the java.util documentation, it's a uuid V2. Which brings me to the question, is it possible to generate a V4 via the GS Utilities interface`, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. Because your new question is different from this question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Agree. Posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292330/create-a-uuid-version-4-via-utilities-getuuid-in-google-sheets

Comment: @tivoni Thank you for your response. About your new question, now, I noticed that your new question has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 28):

[thinkyfish formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672701/) corrected, based on broofa's response at [How do I create a GUID / UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid)

`=CONCATENATE(MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),"-",MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),"-4",MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),"-",MID("89ab",RANDBETWEEN(1,4),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),"-",MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1))`

UUID Version 4 compliance.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the value from recalculating everytime the sheet is updated? EDIT: Seems like this is impossible when using ```RANDBETWEEEN```, but may be [possible using psuedo random values](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120983/how-can-i-generate-a-random-number-that-does-not-change-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Appsheet can help with that using the "initial value". Also: `DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 16^8-1), 8)`

Answer (score 5):

> the created uuid is changed with the time.

I think this problem could not be solved without using the Apps Script.
For example:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var values = sheet.getRange('A1:A10').getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  // When a cell is empty, set a uuid to the cell.
  if (!values[i][0]) {
    sheet.getRange('A' + (1 + i)).setValue(Utilities.getUuid());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried creating a pure sheet function that creates full uuid's just with sheet code and this is what I ended up with it's pretty silly but it does seem to work.  It will re-generate every time the sheet updates so this might not be useful but I wanted to post it anyway because there wasn't a pure sheet implementation available.

`=CONCATENATE(MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),"-",MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),"-",MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),"-",MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),"-",MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1),MID("0123456789abcdef",RANDBETWEEN(1,16),1))`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the details on this thread.  What I ended up doing is creating a macro that will fill all the selected cells in a range each with their own UUID.  I use this approach to set a value in selected cells and not worry about "overwriting" them.  I can use Protect Range to avoid the cells being updated inadvertently.

This script has 2 checks:

1. selected range must cover just a single column
2. all selected cells must be blank (i.e. no selected cell can have a value)

If the above 2 constraints are met, then each cell gets filled with a value.  Here's the macro code:

```js
function fillSelectedWithUUIDs() {
  let curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let curSelection = curSheet.getSelection();
  let curRange = curSelection.getActiveRange();

  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  if (curRange.getNumColumns() !== 1) {
    ui.alert(`Range must only contain one column.`);
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < curRange.getNumRows(); i++) {
    let curCell = curRange.getCell(1 + i, 1);
    if (curCell.getValue() !== "") {
      ui.alert(`ERROR: Cannot overwrite value in cell (${curCell.getA1Notation()})`);
      return;
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < curRange.getNumRows(); i++) {
    curRange.getCell(1 + i, 1).setValue(Utilities.getUuid())
  }

  ui.alert(`Added ${curRange.getNumRows()} UUIDs`);
}
```

Hope this is of use to some!

Answer (score 0):

Define Named Functions

Function Name: RANDOM_HEX
Formula definition:
=LOWER(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 15)))

Function Name: RANDOM_HEX_BY_LENGTH
Argument placeholders [OPTIONAL]: length
Formula definition:
=JOIN("", MAKEARRAY(1, length, LAMBDA(rowIndex, columnIndex, RANDOM_HEX())))

Function Name: UUID_V4
Formula definition:
=JOIN("-", RANDOM_HEX_BY_LENGTH(8), RANDOM_HEX_BY_LENGTH(4), RANDOM_HEX_BY_LENGTH(4), RANDOM_HEX_BY_LENGTH(4), RANDOM_HEX_BY_LENGTH(12))

Or...

=JOIN("-", JOIN("", MAKEARRAY(1, 8, LAMBDA(rowIndex, columnIndex, LOWER(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 15)))))), JOIN("", MAKEARRAY(1, 4, LAMBDA(rowIndex, columnIndex, LOWER(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 15)))))), JOIN("", MAKEARRAY(1, 4, LAMBDA(rowIndex, columnIndex, LOWER(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 15)))))), JOIN("", MAKEARRAY(1, 4, LAMBDA(rowIndex, columnIndex, LOWER(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 15)))))), JOIN("", MAKEARRAY(1, 12, LAMBDA(rowIndex, columnIndex, LOWER(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 15)))))))

I recommend Named Functions!

Comment: `RANDOM_HEX_BY_LENGTH(8)` can be simplified to  `DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 16^8-1), 8)`

Comment: Though admittedly, it doesn't work if it's too high, in which case, you'd have to do 2x6 instead of a 12.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seeing a lot of overly complicated solutions for this. We can generate a UUID4 via this:

`=lower(CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 16^8-1), 8),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 16^4-1), 4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 16^4-1), 4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 16^4-1), 4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 16^6-1), 6)),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 16^6-1), 6)))`

Remove the `lower` if you want the uppercase version.

This is based on the formula from here:
https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10105828?hl=en

> The following spreadsheet formula, suitable for Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets, will generate a unique ID consistent with those generated by AppSheet's UNIQUEID() function:
>
> =DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 4294967295), 8)
> To generate a lower-case key, use the following formula:
>
> =LOWER(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 4294967295), 8))

`4294967295` is just the actual value of `16^8-1`. We use `2x16^6` rather than a `16^12` because `16^12` exceeds the max allowed value for RANDBETWEEN.

Though I imagine:

```
function uuid() {
  return Utilities.getUuid();
}
```

Is probably still the better answer if you are scripting, but if you want to avoid scripting the formula above should do the job.

Answer (score -2):

Try this if you just want a formula you can quickly drop in.  The caveat here is that you won't have any alpha characters in the generated value, but these should be "good enough" for nearly any purpose regardless.

```
=RANDBETWEEN(10000000,99999999) & "-" & RANDBETWEEN(1000,9999) & "-" & RANDBETWEEN(1000,9999) & "-" & RANDBETWEEN(1000,9999)& "-" & RANDBETWEEN(1000,9999) & RANDBETWEEN(10000000,99999999)
```