# How to add AM/PM in googlesheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im having trouble adding AM/PM in my formula in google sheet

This is my formula

```
=IF(ISDATE(H7),TEXT(NOW(),"h:mm"),"nt")
```

If you seend the format of `NOW()` is `h:mm` that gives you time only like 10:00

Now how can I add AM/PM after `h:mm`

Answer (score 2):

How about this modified formula?

#### Modified formula:

```
=IF(ISDATE(H7),TEXT(NOW(),"h:mm AM/PM"),"nt")
```

- Official document says as follows.

  > `AM/PM` for displaying hours based on a 12-hour clock and showing AM or PM depending on the time of day.
- When it's `2020/07/27 15:00:00`, above formula returns `3:00 PM`.

#### Reference:

- [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)

Comment: This one works but i have a question, I did try this, but when I add a value in a new cell the `NOW()` is updating. How can you prevent it ?

Comment: @Cyrille Con Morales Thank you for your comment. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your question, for example, how about converting the formula to a text using a script by executing with the OnEdit event trigger? By this, the value can be fixed. You can see the sample script at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51245218). If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: what is mean is the `now()` function when you use it to other cell it changes the value or it is updating

Comment: @Cyrille Con Morales Thank you for replying. I apologize my replying was not useful for your situation. When `=NOW()` is put to a cell, for example, when other cell is edited, the cell with `=NOW()` is updated. About this situation, I thought that you wanted to fix the value. So I proposed a workaround. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.