# Create a UUID version 4 via Utilities.getUuid in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, uuid

*Post is related to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245218/how-to-generate-an-uuid-in-google-sheet/51254597?noredirect=1#comment131123531_51254597)*

According to the [Utilities.getUuid Google Scripts docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#getUuid()):

> Get a UUID as a string (equivalent to using the
> java.util.UUID.randomUUID()

Looking at the [java.util.UUID.randomUUID() docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html):

> The variant field contains a value which identifies the layout of the
> UUID. The bit layout described above is valid only for a UUID with a
> variant value of 2, which indicates the Leach-Salz variant.

Does `variant value of 2` means `UUIDv2`?
Assuming `Utilities.getUuid` generates s `UUIDv2` and it doesn't pass `UUIDv4` validation:

My project needs to generate UUIDv4 in JS code. Also, there's a restriction on _ids: they have to be `UUIDv4` (it is non-negotiable, existing db etc).

Is it possible to generate a UUID V4 via the GS `Utilities` interface?

Or - is my best option to copy & call JS code which generates a UUIDv4 instead?

Comment: It is type4. There's a version field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variant is different from version. According to [RFC4144](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt), Variant denotes,

> some bits of the eight octet variant field specified below determine finer structure.

> The variant field determines the layout of the UUID.  That is, the interpretation of all other bits in the UUID depends on the setting of the bits in the variant field

Version means

> The version number is in the most significant 4 bits of the timestamp (bits 4 through 7 of the time_hi_and_version field).

The `Uuid` generated is  version 4. [RFC4144](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) describes the following format for `Uuid`:

```
  UUID                   = time-low "-" time-mid "-"
                           time-high-and-version "-"
                           clock-seq-and-reserved
                           clock-seq-low "-" node
  time-low               = 4hexOctet
  time-mid               = 2hexOctet
  time-high-and-version  = 2hexOctet
  clock-seq-and-reserved = hexOctet
  clock-seq-low          = hexOctet
  node                   = 6hexOctet
  hexOctet               = hexDigit hexDigit
  hexDigit =
        "0" / "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9" /
        "a" / "b" / "c" / "d" / "e" / "f" /
        "A" / "B" / "C" / "D" / "E" / "F"

The following is an example of the string representation of a UUID as
a URN:

urn:uuid:f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6
```

If the id is `f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6`,

The third sequence `11d0` represents `time-high-and-version`, the first  number here is the version in variant 2, i.e., `1` in `11d0`. All the ids provided by [`Utilties.getUuid()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#getuuid) are of type 4. They'll look like

```
f81d4fae-7dec-41d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6
```

- Variant - 8th octet(starting from 0): `a7` in`a765` above[Since this field is multiplexed with clock-seq-and-reserved, it'll be between 8...a in variant 2]
- Version - 6th octet's most significant bit: `4` in `41d0` above

Also see [variants in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants)